# How can I copy one vector block to the other

Tags: c++, memory

I used array to store the data, but I replaced with vector, so I would like to replace all the c operators with c++ operators. I used memcpy to copy one memory blocks

```
for (i = 0; i < rows_; i++)
    memcpy((T *) &tmp.data_[cols_ * i], (T *) &a.data_[cols_ * (2 * i + 1)], rows_ * sizeof(T));
```

It's also working with vectors, I just want to know is there an equivalent function in c++?

I tried the copy:

```
std::copy(tmp.data_[cols_ * i], tmp.data_[cols_ * i+rows], a.data_[cols_ * (2 * i + 1)]);
```

but I'm receiving the following error:

```
error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
```

For example:

I have an 2xnxn size array and I'm using the for cycle to make an nxn array instead. for example I have 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, my new array has to be the following: 3 4 7 8. I used memcpy to achieve this, but I don't know how can I achieve in c++

Comment: have you tried [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)?

Comment: `std::copy`. In fact you should be using it with arrays as well.

Comment: Yes I tried:
std::copy(tmp.data_[cols_ * i], tmp.data_[cols_ * i+rows], a.data_[cols_ * (2 * i + 1)]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) if you copy from `array` to `vector`

```
  int from_array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  std::vector<int> to_vector;

  int array_len = sizeof(from_array)/sizeof(int);
  to_vector.reserve(array_len);
  std::copy( from_array, from_array+10, std::back_inserter(to_vector)); 
  or C++11
  std::copy( std::begin(from_array), std::end(from_array), std::back_inserter(to_vector));   

  std::vector<int> to_vector2;
  to_vector2.reserve(array_len);
  to_vector2.assign(from_array, from_array + array_len);
```

if copy from vector to vector

```
   std::vector<int> v1;
   std::vector<int> v2;
   v2 = v1; // assign operator = should work
```

if you don't need to keep v1, `std::swap` also works

```
v2.swap(v1);
```

Update:

```
  const int M = 2;
  const int N = 4;
  int from_array[M][N] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};

  std::vector<int> to_vector;
  to_vector.reserve(N);
  int start=2;
  int end = 4;
  for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
  {
    std::copy( from_array[i]+start, from_array[i]+end, std::back_inserter(to_vector)); 
  }
```

Comment: I have an 2xnxn size array and I'm using the for cycle to make an nxn array instead. for example I have 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, my new array has to be the following: 3 4 7 8. I used memcpy to achieve this, but I don't know how can I achieve in c++

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard algorithm [copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/). It is safer than memcpy because it works also for non-POD types. It is sometimes optimized for POD types to result in memcpy. You usually don't use pointers with standard algorithms, but you have to use iterators. To get an iterator you use `begin()` and `end()` methods or free functions. Example:

```
vector<int> a(10, 5);
vector<int> b(5);

copy(a.begin(), a.begin()+5, b.begin());
```

Comment: There's also `vector::assign`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has native `operator=()` which can be used for copying one vector content to another:

```
std::vector<T> x;
std::vector<T> y;
y = x;
```

There is also [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) which works with iterators and allows to have array slices copied.

Comment: The operator=() is not good for me because I'm reorganizing the array blocks